# Update Policy with zero retention on source table

Tags: azure-data-explorer

If we follow the scenario described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy#zero-retention-on-source-table) titled 'Zero retention on source table' , i.e. we have set transactional update policy and treating source tables are only temporary landing points and thus setting softdelete as 0s:-

```
.alter-merge table <TableName> policy retention softdelete=0s
```

Now since the update policy in question is transactional in nature , lets say update policy execution (execution of stored function executed by the update policy) fails , will there be retry ? and how long will Kusto keep retrying? Until the time it attempts retry , where does the data reside? Because source tables are 0 retention , so it won't even exist in source table I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the retry logic is described in the "[transactional policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy#transactional-policy)" section. When the ingestion fails due to transactional update policy, the Data Management cluster will simply send the ingestion command to the source table again based on the logic described in the docs, until the full ingestion command succeeded the data will not be in the source or target tables:

[image]

Comment: So if FailureKind is being shown as Transient in the output of .show ingestion failures , is that a guarantee that Kusto will definitely retry it ? If that's the case, as long as we don't see FailureKind as Permanent we can be sure that there is no data loss (provided there is no failure before data is sent to Kusto Data Engine service).

Comment: Yes, this is correct, based on the retry logic above, once the retry operation exhausted itself (based on that logic) above the ingestion will be abandoned and the ingestion failure will turn into permanent.

Comment: So after exhausting all its retry operations , an entry will be made as Permanent which will be shown in .show ingestion failures command right ?